# Why is there a gap around my text? It isn't present in the freecodecamp example. Extremely basic CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TT5D.jpg). My attempt is on the right.

What is causing mine to have a gap above my  text (which also causes its position to be lowered)?

Here is the source example at FreeCodeCamp:

https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNBOYG

Here is my attempt:

https://codepen.io/headonshoe/pen/jObERrg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing the line-height variable. By default you usually want the font-size to be the same as the line-height. Unless you are doing it intentionally.

```
.projects-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
}
```

With CSS there is always multiple solutions. It looked like the freecodecamp was doing something a little extra with `<span><</span><span>/></span>`.

Comment: You solved it thank you very much!!

BTW their span thing was some decorative elements that appear around the text on mouseover (I'll figure that out separately), so maybe that's how they get everything aligned but I'm not sure.